# Calling functions inside functions vs returning, which is more efficient?

Tags: performance, function, return

In the below 2 cases, which one is more efficient?

**Case 1:**

```
def test(x):
    hello(x)

def hello(y):
    return world(y)

def world(z):
    return z
```

**Case 2:**

```
def test(x):
    a = hello(x)

def hello(y)
    b = world(y)
    return b

def world(z):
    c = z
    return z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** both are just as fast.

Here are the timings on my machine with the CPython 3.7.6 interpreter (on a loop of 10000000 run repeated 3 times):

```
First case: 109 ns
Second case: 111 ns
```

The difference is negligible between the two. Thus, the two are as fast.

Using PyPy (JIT-based interpreter), the JIT compiler is able to optimize both cases and remove all the function calls. Thanks to the JIT, the code can be executed at a zero cost and the time of the two cases is thus exactly the same.

If you use Cython the same kind of things could occur.

**Advice:**

Please do not tweak a Python code with micro-optimizations like this for better performance. Readability takes precedence over performance in Python.*
If you really care about performance of such a thing, please use an alternative interpreter like PyPy or Cython or an integrated Python JIT compiler (such as Numba).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Also, which one is more readable? I’m assuming case 2 would be more readable.

Comment: They are slightly different. There is a missing `return` in `hello` so that they can be considered as equivalent. I personally find the first more readable (with the `return` added).